# MVC3 Checkbox value won't clear

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a fairly straightforward razor view which needs to be used for a questionnaire, which is used repeatedly until it runs out questions. Checkbox is used for select answers, the problem is when I first submit the form when the next set of questions returned the answers I submit in the first time are retained in the second page. For the simplicity I have reduced the program as follows,

Model,

```
public class CheckBoxItemDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBoxModel
{
    public CheckBoxModel()
    {
        Dtos = new List<CheckBoxItemDto>();
    }

    public IList<CheckBoxItemDto> Dtos { get; set; }
}
```

Controller,

```
public class CheckBoxController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        CheckBoxModel model = new CheckBoxModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            model.Dtos.Add(new CheckBoxItemDto(){Id = i,Selected = true});   
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Index(CheckBoxModel mdl)
    {
        CheckBoxModel model = new CheckBoxModel();
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
        {
            model.Dtos.Add(new CheckBoxItemDto() { Id = i, Selected = i % 2 == 0 });
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View,

```
@model CheckBoxTest.Models.CheckBoxModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewPage1";
}

<h2>ViewPage1</h2> 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Dtos.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Dtos[i].Id)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Dtos[i].Selected)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Dtos[i].Selected)
    <br/>
}
<input type="submit" value="Index" /> 
}
```

In the view after post, DisplayFor and CheckBoxFor column values are different. But It should be the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By the sound of it your `ModelState` is still holding its previous values when you return the view.  Try clearing the `ModelState` in your post action:

```
ModelState.Clear();
CheckBoxModel model = new CheckBoxModel();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Index` action method that gets run for a POST, ASP.Net MVC is expecting the resulting View to display validation errors. Therefore, the HTML Helper method `CheckBoxFor` looks in the `ModelState` before the `Model`, so it can display the "invalid" value to the user.

If you're not using the View from a POST action to display errors, you can clear the ModelState as [Dangerous suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194119/77090). Or, you could use the "Post-Redirect-Get" pattern: in your POST action method, display the same View if there are errors, or else redirect to a GET view that displays something else.